# Removing creases with sub divison

Tags: mesh

Im trying to create a cyclinder with the bottom and top rounded but when i use the Sub divison modifier it leaves these creases at both ends and if i use a loop cut to smooth it out it makes the object to flat at both ends and not rounded how can i fix this?[image]

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges

Comment: @MrZak I think he is trying to *not* have sharp edges.

Comment: @PGmath yes, probably it was better to say the main thing is topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those ugly creases are caused by the n-gon cap.  The Subsurf modifier works best with quads and doesn't work well at all with n-gons.

Here are two alternate methods of filling the cap which produce quads, and thus much better subdivision modeling.

[image]

- The first example was made by selecting the n-gon face and then hitting <kbd>E</kbd> (exturde) and then <kbd>S</kbd> to scale the extrusion inward.  You could move the extruded part up to make the top less flat.
- The second example was made by joining half the opposing vertices, making a quad fan.  This could also be done by using the *Grid Fill* option.  Again, the central vertex could be lifted up to make the top more round.