# Is there an Edge Crease tool for the Smooth option (similar to that used for the Sub surf modifier)

Tags: edges

I know this is a long shot (and I'm going to have to go back and delete/recreate my arrays with a subsurf mod) but since I've already locked in most of them:

I was wondering if there is a tool that acts as an Edge Crease (for the smooth option) that'll allow me to sharpen up some of the edges on a tire.

Currently my rendered tire looks like this:

[image]

When smoothing things definitely get a little TOO smooth.

[image]

In the end, I'm ok if there's not, just hoping to save some time :)

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges; also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface

Comment: Are you interested in a linear intepolation of the shading or just making hard edge? E.g. Edge crease range is -1;1. while Mark Sharp is a boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

Edge Split modifier may be the thing you are looking for?

After applying the modifier to the object you could use "Mark sharp"
to further modify the behavior of the modifier.

Hope it helps.

[image]