# Can't get Auto Smooth to work on extruded spiral

Tags: mesh

This should be super simple but somehow I can't get it to work

- Create a spiral
- Give it some extra turns
- convert to mesh
- extrude a little on the x-axis (so it looks like a roll of paper)
- tick auto smooth

But it still looks like this:
[image: extruded sprial]

I've also tried the Smooth Modifier but no difference there either .... ?

Comment: Aside from using *AutoSmooth* turn on Smooth shading in the *Toolshelf*. At the moment all the faces continue being flat shaded. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges

Comment: Thanks - I can't find Smooth shading in the toolshelf but did 'W' in edit mode and Shade Smooth (is this the same thing). The faces are now perfect but the edges at the top and bottom are still straight lines with angles which looks a bit wierd.

Comment: You could add a subsurf modifier. You find the flat/smooth options only in object mode.

Comment: Found the flat/smooth options thanks but no improvement. The faces are find, it is the edges at the top and bottom of the roll that are still straight lines. Add a solidify modifier and the faces still look smooth but the darker shadows show the original unsmoothed faces

Comment: I'm not sure what does it mean "the darker shadows show the original faces";  if you want [smooth thick](http://i.imgur.com/qHC3eue.jpg) spiral you add **Solidify**, **Subsurf**, set shading to *Smooth*, use *AutoSmooth* (or **EdgeSplit** mod) and add some loopcuts to the curve to make it like beveled, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface.

Comment: Edge split works at the top and bottom when I extrude a plane along the spiral and fill caps but when I add Subsurf the ends of the coil are no longer flat. However that wasn't my original question so have posted it here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48336/how-to-make-a-thick-smooth-metal-coil-using-plane-extruded-along-spiral. Thanks for comments, pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the spiral enable the **Add Curve: Extra Objects** plugin.

[image]

Then do Add->Curve->Spirals

[image]

For a smooth curve, don't convert your spiral into a mesh, keep it as curve and extrude it on the geometry section:

[image]

To add thickness use a solidify modifier:

[image]

Comment: That's a great method and with Subsurf it looks smooth. I need thickness as well though which is proving a nightmare but I'll start a new question for that!

Comment: @Doodled see edited answer

Comment: yes, I'd tried the solidify modifier but I needed sharp corners at the top and bottom and ends of the roll. Got an answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48336/how-to-make-a-thick-smooth-metal-coil-using-plane-extruded-along-spiral?