# Subsurf modifier rounding sharp edges

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges

I tried to apply a Subdivision Surface on a part of my object. I can't keep the angles sharp, they all turn into rounded angles.

The angle before applying the Subdivision surface...
[image]

...And after
[image]

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges/735#735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep hard your edges, use the Crease. You find it on the right

[image]

The crease makes your edges purple, in order to show you wich one will remain hard or not.

Usually is set on 0.00 . . . Max it from 0.00 to 1.00 and your edges will keep their shape after a subdivision surface.

For example:
Before subdivision

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fuboski. I tried and it works perfectly. Do I need to apply an Edge Split?

Comment: It dipends . . .take care: edge split will need with the shading not for the subdivision surface. In order to undertsand better their function i suggest you this thread http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges

Comment: @Grobby if you are keeping the model in Blender exclusively then by all means yes if it helps but I think adding supporting geometry (edge loops) is an equally favorable option. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges/735#735 for some tips.

Comment: @Grobby if I answered your question please tick it as correct (the V) in order to close this thread

Comment: Where can I tick my question a answered?

Comment: @IKIsR I just read you post. Is it better to use the edge loops or the Mean Crease to make sharp corners?

Comment: The V is near the beginning of my answer on the left; there is the 1 between 2 "arrows" (2 triangles) . . .  the V is just below.

Comment: @Grobby Sorry I missed this, the use case largely depends. For high poly models or stuff you export I think edge loops are better, for anything not the focal point or will remain lowpoly or inside Blender, creases can be useful.