# How to keep edges around the square hole sharp?

Tags: mesh, edges

I need help on how to keep the edges of this squar hole sharp please. If I use the edge loop method, yes it keeps the edges shard but causes pinching at the same time. As for edge split method, it just causes the hole to be a sharp rounded square. Any advice?

[image: Using Edge Loops that cause pinching in the mesh]

[image: screenshot-2]

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface/6426#6426 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63770/subsurf-modifier-rounding-sharp-edges or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42264/how-to-get-hard-edges-when-using-subsurf-modifier/42267#42267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Edge Crease by pressing Shift + E after selecting the edges around and inside the hole.

Make sure you select all of these edges for the desired result.

[image]

I added an Edge Split modifier at the end to get rid of the smooth shading artifacts.

Hope this helps!