# Subsurf on a crown. How can I smooth some edges and keep others sharp?

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]

How can I smooth all crown but don't smooth the top of the crown? I did a subdivision surface, but this didn't work. All crown became smooth and changed form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subsurf modifier rounding sharp edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63770/subsurf-modifier-rounding-sharp-edges)

Answer (score 11):

Another approach:

[image]

- Create a Z-scaled, subduvided UV sphere, and a capless cylinder, at the origin.
- Give the cylinder a few horizontal loops,  and assign it a Srinkwrap modifier to the sphere; drag it down to a good-looking position in Z
- Select the N,S,E,W vertices on the top loop of the Cylinder, and with Proportional Edit / Linear falloff, drag the points up in Z
- Proportional off, Median Pivot Point, scale the bottom loop to 0 in Z
- Assign a Solidify modifier, with 'Crease' set to 1 for Inner, Outer, and Rim.

The crease will hold against any subdivision.. after applying the modifiers you can extrude down the cylindrical headband, etc. (You might not even need subdivision, maybe AutoSmooth will do..)

EDIT: .... But as moonboots points out, it's worth taking a little time to put in a bevel after applying the Solidify and a level of subdivision around the rims, and then across the peaks and troughs, as shown:

[image]

Comment: nice, but instead of crease, which hurts, maybe you can finish by some bevels, first on the edges all around then on the crest, this one seems to work: https://zupimages.net/up/19/09/urwa.jpg

Comment: @moonboots  Quite right. Shall I staple it into the answer? Probably best here in the comment.

Comment: yes sure do it!

Answer (score 10):

add a subsurface modifier, select some edges and crease the edges
[image]

[image]

it's a little easier of you crease the entire thing, then select a few edges and reduce the crease where you want it softer or rounder.

creasing is quite versatile :D

[image]

Comment: That's the most appropriate non-destructive solution

Comment: @Kroltan I agree on the non-destructive point.. and it's probably absolutely good enough.. but I also agree with moonboots that adding a bevel improves the quality of the sharp edges, to finish, after the model is settled? See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/132922/35559)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to make a crown, maybe there's a simpler?

- Build a basic cube, delete its two side faces, give it a *Mirror* modifier.
- Drag up its central edge, add 3 vertical edge loops.
- Add some additional edge loops close to the angles so that it will sharp them later.
- Give your object an *Array* modifier. Choose a *Count* of 4. Enable the *Merge* option.
- Give your object a *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode. Choose an *Angle* value of 360°. If it doesn't turn around the Z axis, apply the rotation of your object.
- At last, give your object a *Subsurf* modifier (and press the *Smooth Shading* button on the *Tools* panel).
- Move a bit your edges with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to sharp the crest and the low of the crown.
- Apply the modifiers (except the *Subsurf* if possible), remove the doubles (where the 360° joint happens).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just above the Mean Crease setting that kei suggested is the Mean Bevel Weight (for edges, not the one for vertices).  My usual method is to set the edges Mean Bevel Weight to 1.0, then add a Bevel modifier, making sure it's above the Subdivision Surface modifier in the modifier stack, and in the Bevel modifier making sure the Weight button is selected, not None.  Adjust the Bevel modifier's other settings, Width and Segments, to taste; Segments is usually 3 for me.

This allows you to control the rounding / beveling of those specific edges separately from whatever the Subdivision Surface modifier does.

Alternatively, instead of using Mean Bevel Weight you could use a vertex group.

Sometimes you simply want the "obvious" edges not subdivided by the Subdivision Surface modifier, for example with a cylinder I want the top and bottom edges left alone.  In that case I can select the Bevel modifier's Angle button, changing the Angle value to 80 or whatever if necessary.  Using this method, if you add a cylinder and set the number of vertices (sides) to 6, it will still turn into a cylinder when you add the Subdivision Surface and you have the Levels high enough (3 or more).

Comment: In the. follow up [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/132890/35559) you describe this as a 'hack'? I don't think so.. I often use it with segments 2 and profile 1 as a direct substitute for hand-cut holding loops. I still find care has to be taken with the widths (weights)  to avoid that problem with interpolation 'leapfrogging' at concave corners.. It would be lovely to be able to automate this away and still wind up with clean topology.. many of the questions on this forum would disappear..still looking for it... :)

Answer (score 1):

Add in more loop cuts on the subsurf mod.  That should do it.  I take it that smooth shading doesn't work?