# Geometry issues in imported FBX file?

Tags: modeling, file-format

A 3D model created in formZ was converted from .fmz to .fbx. After importing the FBX file I have a 3D model that has quite some strange dark grey colours in Solid shading. Now I am far from an expert in analysing meshes but I have the experience that there is something wrong with the topology when there are dark tones in the 3D model.

[image]

Is there something wrong with this model and if Yes, is this repairable in Blender ?

[image]

Comment: It's a mix between z-fighting, not recalculated normals and smooth shading without Edge Split modifier. E.g. window glass for some reason is present in both objects, house contour and window frames, so they overlap.

Comment: MASSA mesh is pretty distorted too. It would need some cleaning before rendering. Also materials are applied quite randomly, so You would have to apply them again in Blender in some reasonable manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These black spots indeed are caused by incorrect topology, as well as inorrectly oriented normals and unsplitted faces.

1. Regarding house contour, which is called MASSA.

   [image: screenshot of faces causing z-fighting]

   In original file faces from the house itself and from the windows are overlapping and closing each other. In the final version of the file the selected faces as well as ones closing other windows are deleted.

   [image: screenshot of the badly filled faces]

   These are faces overlapping with themselves, at the same time they close windows. It may be better to recreate them; one way can be subdiving top edges of the house contour, and filling new faces based on new vertices.
2. Regarding the roof which is called DAK_ZWART. I think the face selected on the picture shouldn't be there as the window continues under it.

   [image: screenshot of wrongly filled face]
3. Tiles on the roof have overlapping geometry seen through them; it's caused by the bottom big face. Just delete it:

   [image: screenshot of tiles]
4. With above mentioned, either split normals of all the objects (I used *Autosmooth* option in *Object Data* tab, it can be Edge Split modifier as well, if you plan to export the mesh use modifier only) or set the shading to *Flat* to make house and other man-made objects look more flat and not too round. See [How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges) for details.
   The normals were recalculated (see  [Why are some faces in my mesh darker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker)) and some double vertices removed for all the objects as well.

   [image: screenshot of the final house]

   [image]

Comment: hello Mr Zak. Thanks for your answer. I don't understand your number 3 regarding the tiles on the roof

Comment: @OldMan there was a face (only one, but it was as big as the roof)) just below those roof tiles. It was located close to the top of the tiles and hence was slightly visible through them (note small triangles-like patterns on every tile in the image to the 3). I deleted that face as that's the easiest way (and it won't be visible), but it's possible to move it slightly down if it's needed.