# Edges between flat faces and smooth faces are weird

Tags: faces, edges

I have a problem where the edges between flat faces and smooth faces are weird, but I can't figure out how to solve this. It shows up in render and makes the model look pretty bad. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!  [image: Alien Space Ship]

[image]

Comment: Could you please post an Edit Mode wireframe screenshot of your model also? It may be helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: It's probalby a similar issue to the one shown in this post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Paul Gonet It dosn't let me add another link because I don't have enough reputation

Comment: @tacofisher I can't really figure out what's going on there :/

Comment: Go to the link I posted and search for the answer on the very bottom, you have to enable autosmooth , this will keep the smoothness everywhere except the faces that form an angle greater than a specified value (30 by default). All you need to do is check the box that says Auto smooth

Comment: @tacofisher soooo.... I can't mark a comment as an answer, if you'd like to post that as an answer then that'd be nice.