# Roughness at Modeling

Tags: modeling

[image: rughness]

[image: roughness]

Hello guys,at the pictures you can see bottom of the cup and the glass are rough. How can I solve.Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42264/how-to-get-hard-edges-when-using-subsurf-modifier/42267#42267

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep sharp edges when using subdivision surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82477/cylinder-has-small-wierd-bumps-when-using-subdivision-surface

Answer (score 0):

You need to add edges at the bottom of the cup as shown below:[image]
[image]
That will solve the problem.

Comment: That will not solve the problem rather than just hide it. The problem is in the big Ngon in the bottom which has to be converted into something else, only then the problem will go away.

Comment: Then you can use Ctrl+T then Alt+J.It will triangulate the Ngon.