# Auto Smooth can it be applied permanently to a mesh?

Tags: mesh, topology

Is it possible to apply auto smooth permanently to a mesh, so that it looks that way even if auto smooth is deselected and the changes that auto smooth makes can be seen in edit mode?

*Update*: I am referring to the Data tab, Normals group, Auto Smooth check box.

Comment: There are a lot of different auto smooths in Blender. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: @YusaMac205 I'm aware only of [Auto Smooth option in the Object Data > Normals rollout](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/smoothing.html#auto-smooth) which is called like that, what are the others?. As for the question it's possible to add Edge Split modifier and apply it which will be the same provided the same options were used.

Comment: @Mr Zak, Edge Split does it. Please change your comment to an answer and I will accept...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Auto Smooth* option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/smoothing.html#auto-smooth) and [Edge Split modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/edge_split.html) give essentially the same result [starting from Blender 2.71](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8720/1245) when the support for the sharp edges and split normals preview in the viewport was added for the *Auto Smooth*.

There is one difference though - *Auto Smooth* doesn't actually split vertices, it only shows them as split ones. Hence the result of the *Auto Smooth* is visible in Edit mode but is not editable (e.g. to move out the faces which fell under the angle threshold).

To preview the split normals in Edit mode uncheck the *Auto Smooth* and add Edge Split modifier, then apply it (depending on the case it has to be in the bottom of the stack so it doesn't interfere with other modifiers and has to be applied last).

It is still possible to undo the results made with the modifier by removing doubles in Edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

Yes finally found a workaround

you may *export* the mesh to .fbx or .obj and then *re-import* it in to blender.

The sharp edges will be marked sharp in edit mode.