# S Shaped Curved opening

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to create this light saber, but I can't seem to achieve this opening because when I smooth it out it turns out deformed. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: ...any better quality image? show your try (before/after smoothing) if possible or upload file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit your question pasting the provided link

Comment: A better image would be nice but maybe this could help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges

Comment: Okay thanks guys! Will try the solutions! Sorry for the image