# What causes black shading errors?

Tags: light, shadows

[image]

As the picture shows, the bottom part of the hospital is covered with shadow and I don't know why. The face normals are not flipped. This happens in both solid view and rendered view.

What causes these black shadows?

[image]

Comment: Are there black textures/materials applied to the dark parts?

Comment: no it is the same as the front of the hospital ..
they have same object

Comment: Is it the same in the Solid view mode? Please upload your blend using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and update your post so we can investigate it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use **smooth shading** on a [non-manifold mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry), which does not work properly.

Non-manifold means e.g. that some edges have more than two faces, and therefore the surface is not closed but has forks. It is impossible for Blender to tell how to shade these faces properly.
[image]

For your mesh, one way is to seperate the floors into a new object. This way the mesh will be manifold again, but unconnected.
[image: seperation]

Another option is to assign [hard edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges/15527#15527), e.g. using the Edge Split Modifier. This way some edges are shaded flat and others smooth. Flat shading works with non-manifold mesh the same as with manifold mesh. Because in this case the non-manifold spots have large angles, shading problems will be solved.

Comment: THANK YOU THAT WORK !
can u tell me about flat shading ?
what is the disadvantage of using that ?

Comment: There are no advantages and disadvantages, you use each whenever you need them. Flat shading is for polygonal or square-ish models, smooth shading is for rounded or curved surfaces.