# Smooth shading not smoothing everything as expected

Tags: modeling

I have a mesh that is not behaving the way I expect when it comes to smooth shading. For example, here is the mesh (it is all one piece) shaded smooth (as compared to a Blender Cylinder to highlight the differences):

[image]

And here it is shaded flat (again, as compared to the cylinder)

[image]

I expect the handle area to be smooth just like the cylinder (you can notice the purple structures smoothing some edges, but not all).

I already:

- Made sure there is no `edge split` modifier on the mesh
- Selected all edges and did a `Clear Sharp` operation
- Selected all vertices and removed doubles in case there are un-merged vertices

Here's the file for reference: [image]

Comment: Exporting the mesh as an `obj` and then re-importing it shows that all edges are marked as _sharp_. Clearing the sharp edges fixes the issue. However, the original blender model is still behaving strangely as if its data structure is corrupted.

Comment: @MrZak there are no internal faces as far as I can tell (I deleted just one face and it made a hole instead of showing another face if there was any). Please see my comment above where it seems that the blender mesh itself got corrupted somehow...?

Comment: If you want someone to look into your file then upload it here - http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, corrupted data structure is something I expect as the last possibility (and I can't imagine how can that be done)

Comment: @MrZak Thanks, I have uploaded the file. It is a fairly simple model. I'm sure I must have done something accidentally.

Comment: You have AutoSmooth enabled, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8720/1245, in general it's (almost) the same as Edge Split mod. As the object is pretty lowpoly there isn't much difference in the smooth and flat shading, still it can be seen in Solid shading (e.g. horizontal loopcuts). Either increase its threshold or deactivate it.

Comment: @MrZak That's it! Thanks for pointing that out. If you put that as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just disable "Autosmooth" option.

[image]