# STL file quality decreases

Tags: export

[image][image: the lower quality STL file]The stl file that I export the quality seems to lower, it goes from a higher quality to a lower quality. Any help on how to export at full quality?

Comment: There are no "quality" settings when exporting 3D models for the most part, polygons are exported as-is, non are removed or added without explicit user intervention. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: The STL has a lot less Polygons compared to the original model was 46mb whereas the STL is only 14.6mb, so the quality seems to have decreased.

Comment: I have added a second image to show the difference.

Comment: Looks about the same to me. One is [smooth shaded](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges) the other is not.

Comment: Smoothing messes up the model, there are a lot less polygons on the stl then the original blender model.

Comment: Make sure all modifiers are applied before export. Generally there is *Apply Modiifiers* option in STL export but first it has to be enabled and second it isn't necessarily applying modifiers with those options which you see in viewport

Comment: How do you get the Apply modifiers settings I can't find it.

Comment: see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#the-modifier-stack