# Some kind of Sharp issue?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, objects, edges

and thank you for taking the time.
I have been struggling with my object for some time now in an attempt to solve this issue by myself, but now I feel that relying on help from others is something that I must. I appreciate any feedback that leads to a solution.

After a long time I decided to pursue one of my old works to make something of this object, a pity leaving it behind really. I encountered an issue I recall having managed to deal with before, but no matter what thread or video I have looked up has not managed to bring a solution to this matter:

[image]
The middle line is a big pain to me.

This object is a single and merged object. It has already been smoothed out, even from what looks to be a Sharp Edge? The surface is a single one and my texture covers it as one surface, but lightning is distributed differently on either side.

[image]
Blue lines are running along this supposed edge, but even after smoothing/removing these, the line remains. No matter what feature I have tried to dwell into the line remains. I can't remember what I did in the past, but with a command I was able to remove the middle line and make lightning as one unified surface.

Help appreciated :) thank you.

Comment: It could be a modifiers fault, a fault in split geometry (not properly merged edges). Could you post the geometry for further analysis? Possible solution @ https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15519/53220

Comment: Why not use Autosmooth and sharp marking instead of edgesplit ? It's way better and hassle free.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Sadly, I have tried all those options already but that dividing edge remains. I am uploading for analysis, .obj format I hope that is alright :)
https://github.com/Vemone/Projectss

Comment: Further assistance is appreciated :)