# How to deal with this edge

Tags: objects, edges

[image]
Hello everyone,

I have done everything I can to deal with the line in the middle in an attempt to smooth it and turn it into a single surface but not been able to succeed in the end and wonder if any of you wish to take a look at the piece and help me out. It is part of an old object of mine that I worked on a long time ago and I have no idea what I pressed back then!

Despite having asked for help about this issue before, and been reading up help pages such as [How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges?noredirect=1&lq=1) it has not managed to help me solve  the issue unless I was doing something wrong. No matter what features and tools I have tried using, the line stays and won't go, I sharpen the object or smooth it, the line stays.

Help appreciated :) I will add a download for analysis if anyone wants to take a look.
 [github.com/Vemone/Projectss](https://github.com/Vemone/Projectss)

Comment: Please use accept and/or up vote option if answer helped you. Avoid using answer as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

[image: final]

First of all go to **Edit Mode**, select all and <kbd>W</kbd> > **Remove Double**, than select this edge and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > **Clear Sharp**.

[image: sharp]