# How to combine circular two shapes and subdivision surface properly and curved cylinder cap?

Tags: topology, subdivision-surface

[image]

I can't find a way to combine the two circular shapes, and then subdivision surface properly. 
The bottom circle is curved so the face has to be made out of horizontal quads.

Subsurf a curved cylinder cap???

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this kind of topology could work, tell me if it's ok:

[image]

Comment: Somehow I was able to replicate your model, except for the top part. But my concern is at the bottom, how to make the surface of a circle curve?

Comment: make the same topology then drag the bottom on the Y axis with proportional editing activated

Comment: No, it look dented infront. The polygon circle need to be edge side down so the face can be fill with horizontal quads I think, but then I can't insert or loop cut.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, perhaps put an additional picture in your question so that I clearly see what shape you're talking about

Comment: @Tan, I've edited my picture, you can see that my topology allows me to do what you want, no?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the bevel modifier instead.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]