# Normals not working correctly 2.8 Blender

Tags: normals

Normals are not working for me in Blender 2.8. I tried **"CTRL+N"** to recalculate outside but they still are not working. I tried also to turn them inside but it also didn't work. This also happens only when using **"Shade Smooth"**, when I use **"Shade Flat"** normals are fine. Is this something that can be **fixed** or is it something they are still working on in 2.8 Blender?

[image: **Shade Smooth**]
**Shade Smooth**
[image: **Shade Flat**]
**Shade Flat**
[image: Normals]
**Normals**

Comment: You should probably use mark sharp edge and split them, or bevel the edge. The smooth shader do something rely on the interpolation of face(vertices) normal. Without the extra edge to constrain the effect, smooth will turn out bad in some certain area.

Comment: I'll with redo scope and I will add more vertices in the begining.

Comment: Check out this question as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges

Comment: Thank you. Will do.