# Smooth car but leting edged areas stay

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, subdivision-surface, eevee-render-engine

Here is an image of my current model:
[image: car struglle]
Now I must smooth everything a little bit...But I don't want to use subdivision surface. Then I get this result: [image: too smooth] 
If you need to see how it should look like, here is a reference image: [reference image](http://www.nuerburgring-shop.de/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/990x660/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/7/4/74556w.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges/735#735) or [how to smooth an object while retaining hard edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges/735#735)