# Importing OBJ. FBX from MODO

Tags: import

I am trying to export a model from modo to blender and the polygons are coming in with a weird look. I am exporting out of Modo as a FBX & OBJ and I get the same result with both. The polygons appear to be the correct shape but there is odd tearing look on the polygons any idea whats going on here?[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE. It seems like a simple problem with normals. Please share your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so others can take a look. Without that, it's just guessing.

Comment: Here is a file with the same issue of a motor. I imported this one as a .OBJ and the blender file is in the link below. Could you let me know what you do to fix it because I am looking to switch from Modo to blender but I have 6 years worth of work in files and this seems to happen every time I try and import to blender.  
     

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6857" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6857/)

Comment: Hello. There's a simple solution. Go to *Edit Mode* and select all vertices *Select->All*. Then you just split the normals through *Mesh->Normals->Split*. Voilá, solved.

Comment: The solution can be also found in the original thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8720/78972 by none other than the mighty gandalf3.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!