# When I shade smooth I see a weird metal ball

Tags: materials, shaders

Can someone please tell me why when I shade smooth I see this metal ball on my object?

[image]

Comment: Try resetting the normal?

Comment: Tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like the problem is with how smooth shading works.  Basically, all you want is for it to interpolate the normals between each side face, but it's also interpolating normals between the side faces and the top and bottom faces.  You can take a look at this question to see if it proposes any solutions that work for you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges