# Why is there uneven smooth shading?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, shadows, smooth

When creating this mug, some crazy shadows appear when connecting the mug's handle to the actual cup. Auto smooth with normals does not fix this.

[image: issue] [image: edit mode]

Blend File: [image]

Comment: One problem I can see from your image is that the handle has a higher level of subdivision than the cup - the result is the faces on the cup right next to where the handle joins are _N-gon's_ (faces with more than 4 vertices). You can see there are 3 vetrs on one edge not connected to anything.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges/

Comment: there are 2 problems here: ngons and an angle of 90° that makes the shade smooth looks bad, get rid of your ngons (delete some edge loops) and give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier

Answer (score 2):

Big changes in surface angle will cause this.

I would add a little more loops in these areas:

[image: mesh with wireframe]
[image: mesh no overlays]