# How to create a simple extruded box model?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I am new to Blender and was wondering how I'd build a shape like so in blender? I.e. what tools are usually used for these type of organic curves?! the walls are 1mm thick and im wondering how would I draw that shape and set a depth and then give it a flat back as a piece I could then separate to illustrate the bezel and the shape of the curve?

Front view

[image]

side view to illustrate depth

[image]

Comment: This looks a bit too close to request for tutorial, but since its such a simple task maybe its ok?

Comment: @ideasman42 yes, I thought so as well since wasn't an explicit request imo.

Comment: The title was also a hint, `how to do this` - renamed, but think this is candidate to be closed still.

Comment: @ideasman42 changing the title has nominated it. ;) I thought it was valid as he didn't know what tool(s) he needed to create a certain shape. Let's see if it generates any other reactions though, it *is* a bit localized somewhat.

Answer (score 14):

What you are asking for is not one tool but a workflow. There is no one set way to do this, curves can be better for getting rounded edges but mesh modeling can be just as good.

*However*, this is fairly simple and you can achieve the majority of what you ask by just extruding. You can extrude faces, edges and vertices in Blender with the *Extrude* tool. Just select a face, vertex or edge and press <kbd>E</kbd>.

*(Alternatively, you can constrain your extrusions to extruding along the object normal with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>), you can experiment with this.*

I will use the image you provided as a quick example here..

First, get as close as you can to the shape of the object, *(I create the outline of the object from top view)*. I add a plane  and just grab the edges and subdivide a few times using <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide* while in *Edit* mode to get some more geometry. I then move the new vertices to fit the shape of the image as closely as possible. To make it more detailed and *organic* as you ask, you can add more vertices to round out the curved side.

[image]

If the face has not been filled, you can use <kbd>F</kbd> to make a face from several vertices. I then extrude and delete the top face to give it some depth. To get the lid, I just duplicated the object with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and moved the sides down.

[image]

You can take it anywhere from here now.. I have also quickly added a *Solidify* modifier to give it some thickness. Also another note, I wouldn't worry too much as a beginner on getting accurate units etc, If you insist however, you can change the units using the *Scene* tab under *Units*.

To carry on, I recommend that you see these:

- [How can I make sharp geometric 3d models look more realistic?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247/how-can-i-make-sharp-geometric-3d-models-look-more-realistic/248#248)
- [Most efficient way to round edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/811/most-efficient-way-to-round-edges/)
- [When should N-Gons be used, and when shouldn't they?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89/when-should-n-gons-be-used-and-when-shouldnt-they?rq=1)

Comment: The cover of the box you modelled will not fit the box in any way. The border has to be a little bit bigger and it has to be mirrored :D

Comment: @HenrikD haha, you're right. good catch!

Comment: I create the outline of the object from top view). Yes but how do you create the outline?

Answer (score 2):

What you'll probably want is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjOSkSQtGOM) on extruding.

Tools you'll need:

1. The Extrude tool - access with <kbd>E</kbd>
2. The Solidify Modifier - access through the modifiers menu
3. To measure, probably another tutorial or discussion like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151208205434/http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15732&sid=65454d0851162acf56a0a46373a09e07).