# Modeling odd shape

Tags: modeling

I want to replicate the shape of this arcade cabinet (in green). I tried to do this by drawing vertices but this leaves me with a jagged edge rather than smooth.

What is the best way to do this? I also tried the bezier curve but then I cant do the straight bits. Maybe there is something I'm missing, any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Arcade Cabinet]

Comment: You are looking for theSubdivision-Surface modifier.

Comment: But will this not make the square edge round as well?

Comment: This looks promising Ray

Comment: @Acott Not if you use edge loops to hold the corners

Comment: maybe you'll find this useful: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/811/most-efficient-way-to-round-edges