# Maintain shape after subdivision

Tags: modeling

[image: Maintain a rectangle]

This rectangular hole is extruded to the inside, then I tried beveling it to maintain shape, but after I add the subdivision it becomes an ellipse. How do I keep the rectangular shape?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface. Probably also - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/811/most-efficient-way-to-round-edges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it keep its shape by selecting the verts in the area you don't want to be smoothed, and turning the "Mean Crease" setting in  the upper right to 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mantain the shape you have to add "structure" edges.
[image: example of edges added to mantain the structure]

Simply use ctrl-r to add a cut loopand take it near the hole edges. The more cut loop you make and the more they are near the original hole edge, the it will be squared.
Attention that doing this you are increasing the poly count of you geometry.

Also Keith M answer is valid, bat as I know it can give problem in some cases.