# Create nor equal side of cube with fixed width of bavel?

Tags: modeling

I am creating a simple 3d model like a brick. 
I want to add bavel for rounded corner and edge with same width.
But I did it failed, each face with different rounded curve.
Can anyone teach me how to did it well.

my 3d model:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7njgz161u2trof/untitled.dae?dl=0
```

my model width x height x depth = 2.1 x 6 x 1

Thanks!

Comment: welcome Steve Lai ,refer to this [answer 'using bevel'](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248/5113)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But it not work. 
My problem is different side with same radius of rounding.

Comment: If you have rescaled your object, be sure to _apply_ the scale (Ctrl-A) in _Object_ mode before adding the bevel.