# Trying to create a roof with curved intersecting parts

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I am in the process of learning on how to work with Blender, with great advances. Still, I face myself being stuck on working with more complex stuff from my point of view, due to lack of experience.
I would like to know how I can create these intersecting areas of the different roof parts that are also curved a bit. I am struggling on how to approach this without doing this vertex bx vertex. Any ideas or suggestions?

[image: Original image]

[image: My Blender take at it, all individual parts]

Comment: You may want to look into [Subsurf Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247/how-can-i-make-sharp-geometric-3d-models-look-more-realistic), and [subdivision surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface) modelling

Comment: Thanks, I acutally also came to the same conclusion and used the bevel modifier on the connecting edge, after I manually connected both roofs. Still struggling with bevelling a bit, as I need to make the faces on both sides pretty much to the same size, to have the same effect on both sides of the connection.

Comment: Duartes answer can be put in the answered section. Thanks!